# Wingding chars in sql server 2005

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2005, fonts, wingdings

In a winforms application i 'm storing one Wingdings char in a SQL Server 2005 field of type NVARCHAR(1).

Storing, retrieving and showing up this char in a control works fine.

The problem i'm facing is this: how to search for records which have a specific wingding char value: for example

```
Select * from table where FieldWithWingding = valueOfLeftArrowChar
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor pointed me into the correct direction:
it's actually

Select * from table where FieldWithWingding = N'ß'

Works fine!

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 4):

Wingdings is a **font**! Fonts give a special appearance to characters in a given character set. The left-arrow is therefore a character. Look it up in start->all programs->Accessories->System tools->Character map

Your select will be something like:

```
Select * from table where FieldWithWingding = 'ß'
```

Comment: Additionally, you could use the CHR() function.  Character map will also show you the hex code for the character.

Comment: It's actually a typeface. :-P

Comment: @klausbyskov I know it is a font. The problem is when i get the value (using Visual Basic ComboBoxSearch.SelectedItem().ToString) in the debugger i get a value with a...dot. This is pretty useless while debugging.

@GalacticCowboy i cannot see the benefit of using chr() but i will have a closer look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `select Unicode(N'ß'), Nchar(Unicode(N'ß'))`

Use @filter nvarchar(1) or nchar(1) data types